# EXM CD RedirectUrlPage return Null

Tags: exm

I've set up a Sitecore 9 instance in Scaled-Multisite Environment. I sent an email campaign through the EXM but I got an error when I tried to click on the link inside the body email.

**Error in frontend**
[image]
**Error in log**
[image]

I got this error when I tried to click url with this format `<CD-URL>/sitecore modules/Web/EXM/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_eq=XX`

But when I tried to access the url with `<CM-URL>` it's redirected properly.

**Things I've tried**

- Check on CD and CM `exm.master` connectionString - ensuring it's same and can connect.
- Check on CD and CM `EXM.CryptographicKey` and `EXM.AuthenticationKey` - ensuring it's same value.
- Create specific `hostname mapping` under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Email/System/Hostname Mappings` with Original Url : `<CM-URL>` and Public Url : `<CD-URL>`
- Ensure `Base Url` field in `Email Manager Root` is `<CD URL>`

Comment: hey, how did you fix your issue?

Comment: @RosenPetrov I never solved the issue, at the end I put the direct link into the email. Not the `/sitecore modules/Web/EXM/RedirectUrlPage.aspx`.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would be tha there is an item or a template change, which is not published to CD Server. 
It works on CM and you get a nullreference exception on CD Server.

Answer (score 0):

Please also check your settings on the manager Root:

[image: Manager Root Settings]

They are used how the links in the mails are generated.

**Base Url** should point to your live-url, **Preview base URL** should point to your CM-Instance.

Best regards
Dirk